# Fetch value of specific key from nested dictionary and store values in separate variables

Tags: python, dictionary

I have following dictionary:-

```
    dict={'m1': {'ip': '10.250.10.10', 'port': 6697}, 'm2': {'ip': '10.250.10.20', 'port': 6699}}
```

I need to store values of ip in variables i.e

`a = 10.250.10.10`

`b = 10.250.10.20`

Could anyone please let me know how I can achieve this?

Comment: `dict` is a built-in, be careful of name shadowing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `dict` is a built-in function in Python, so I'd avoid using it as a variable name.

To get specific values from a dictionary, you can use the `get` function, which allows you to provide a default value in case the key you're asking for isn't defined. This prevents a `KeyError` that can be raised if you access dictionary elements using square-brackets.

```
d = {'m1': {'ip': '10.250.10.10', 'port': 6697}, 'm2': {'ip': '10.250.10.20', 'port': 6699}}

a = d.get('m1', {}).get('ip', 'not found')
b = d.get('m2', {}).get('ip', 'not found')
c = d.get('m3', {}).get('ip', 'not found')
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

This code gets the `m1` sub-dictionary, passing an empty dictionary as the default, then gets the `ip` value from that dictionary, passing `'not found'` as the default `ip`.

This way, you will still have *some* value in each variable `a`, `b`, and `c`, no matter what the structure of the dictionary you start with. Note that the value of `c` will be `'not found'`, because the sub-dictionary `m3` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a *generator expression* to fetch the `'ip'`, unpack it and store the values into individual variables like:

```
my_dict = {'m1': {'ip': '10.250.10.10', 'port': 6697}, 'm2': {'ip': '10.250.10.20', 'port': 6699}}

a, b = (v['ip'] for v in my_dict.values())
```

Here's a **functional approach** to achieve this **using [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)** and [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) as:

```
from operator import itemgetter

a, b = map(itemgetter('ip'), my_dict.values())
```

Above solutions will give you `a` and `b` as:

```
>>> a
'10.250.10.10'
>>> b
'10.250.10.20'
```

From Python 3.7+, dictionary maintain the order of insertion, and hence value of `a` and `b` can be predicted. For older versions of Python, the order is arbitrary and hence the value of `a` and `b` can not be predicted.

---

If you are on Python version 3.6 or less, and order matters for you, you can sort the dictionary *keys* using [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), and get the *values* based on the sorted order of keys as:

```
sort_dict_values = [my_dict[key] for key in sorted(my_dict)]
# where `sort_dict_values` holds:
#     [{'ip': '10.250.10.10', 'port': 6697}, {'ip': '10.250.10.20', 'port': 6699}]
```

Now you can use `sort_dict_values` (instead of `my_dict.values()`) to perform earlier operations to fetch the `'ip'` preserving the value of `a` and `b` as per your desired behaviour. For example:

```
a, b = map(itemgetter('ip'), sort_dict_values)
                            # ^ instead of `my_dict.values()`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dict={'m1': {'ip': '10.250.10.10', 'port': 6697}, 'm2': {'ip': '10.250.10.20', 'port': 6699}}

a = dict["m1"]["ip"]
b = dict["m2"]["ip"]

print(a, b)
```

OUTPUT:

```
10.250.10.10 10.250.10.20
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
dict = {'m1': {'ip': '10.250.10.10', 'port': 6697},
        'm2': {'ip': '10.250.10.20', 'port': 6699}}

a = dict['m1']['ip']
b = dict['m2']['ip']
```